# In a vuex module, how to globally define a const based on rootstate

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

In my vuex modules, for each action I need to get the **same** value from the root state. Therefore I do as follows:

```
export const actions = {

    action1({ commit, rootState }, payload) {
        const companyId = rootState.userProfile.companyId;
        ....
    },
    action2({ rootState }, payload) {
        const companyId = rootState.userProfile.companyId;
        ....
    },
    ....

}
```

Is there a way to declare this const **only once** in the module, instead of repeating

```
const companyId = rootState.userProfile.companyId;
```

in each action ?

Answer (score 1):

You could import your store in your module file and create a getter to get the value of the `companyId`.

Not using a getter would result in the `companyId` being set only once and not getting the real value on the action runtime:

```
import store from './index.js'

const companyId = () => store.state.userProfile.companyId

export const actions = {

    action1({ commit }, payload) {
        commit('doSomething', companyId())
        ...
    },
    action2({ }, payload) {
        ...
    },
    ...

}
```

You could also make a getter in your module to get the `companyId`:

```
export const actions = {

  action1({ getters }, payload) {
    console.log(getters.companyId)
  }
}

export const getters = {
  companyId (state, getters, rootState) {
    return rootState.userProfile.companyId
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that using the `rootState` parameter is cleaner tho

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry that I was maybe not precise enough: what actually annoys me is to repeat this line of code every time in each action. It is not to use `rootState`, which works perfectly well :)

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. Actually, I may be wrong, but I am wondering if importing the "parent" store in a module is a good pattern.

Comment: Hi @RenaudTarnec, could you elaborate more, maybe with code even, though it wont work. I just want to get better view on your perspective.

Comment: Hi @JeremyWalters. On what exactly would you like me to elaborate? On my original question or on my "doubts" on importing the "parent" store in a "child" module?

Comment: Sorry for not being spesific, but your doubts on importing the parent store in module.

Comment: Ok, as I said I maybe totally wrong, but I see the concept of modules in a vuex store as a parent/children relationship where we import the children modules in the parent store. Therefore the idea of importing, in turn, the parent store into the children modules kind of look weird for me (a sort of import loop). I would be very interested to get to know the position/thoughts of the SO vue.js community on this perception (which may be totally wrong, again :-))

Comment: Hi, I share with you the weirdiness of the thing. However, I can't see any other thing to operate if you do not want to write `rootState.userProfile.companyId` in each action. Another pattern would be to create your module as a function that takes the root store as a parameter and returns the module itself. It would be more like a "dependency injection"..

Comment: @Hammerbot Thanks for sharing you views :-) I think I'll keep doing it with const `companyId = rootState.userProfile.companyId;`.